Error resolving plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.2']

How can solve this for the flutter project ?
I'm expecting to run this on Android.
The error in text format (screenshot above):
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/sony/AndroidStudioProjects/userapp/android/settings.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.2']
> A problem occurred configuring project ':gradle'.
   > Could not read workspace metadata from /Users/sony/.gradle/caches/8.10/kotlin-dsl/accessors/988977859d9b6b0195278c1d04431d6c/metadata.bin

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 644ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Pretty sure the version should be 1.0.0 try changing it to that in settings.gradle.

First Update com.android.application in settings.gradle file
id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
After That come in gradle folder inside wrapper folder you'll find gradle-wrapper.properties add this:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

Then Restart the IDE
